# Sqlite circular dependency trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

The question is about Sqlite DBMS.

I have two tables:

1. describes objects
2. describes dependencies of objects from table 1 { id, id_parent }

How to write an INSERT and UPDATE triggers for table 2 to check for circular dependencies?

Example of objects dependencies:

A -> B -> C --- ok

A -> B -> C -> A --- raise condition

I understand how to check the immediate dependency A -> B, but have no idea how to check for any level.

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the proverbial uphill.

One fairly simple solution, which may or may not be feasible in your circumstances, is to have a constraint on the second table: `id > id_parent`. This will make it impossible to create cyclic graphs:

```
CREATE TABLE deps ( id NOT NULL, id_parent NOT NULL, CHECK ( id > id_parent ) )
```

Comment: Very nice idea which forces the constraint with no significant computation, but it has one side effect in my case. After the tables are initially populated any object can be set as a parent for another object. **id** is PK, so no single child can have multiple parents. Your solution might work if I create a BEFORE trigger which swaps ids of those objects which are affected by INSERT / UPDATE statement if `id < id_parent`. Swapping PKs will only work ok if all transactions are EXCLUSIVE, otherwise data might be either inconsistent on write or dirty on read. I don't really want to swap PKs :(